# Reference Azure Mobile .NET Server SDK NUGET in PCL so I can have models in PCL

Tags: c#, azure, entity, nuget, portable-class-library

I am trying to create a mobile app for windows and andriod that utilizes azure mobile app service (Azure Mobile Apps NOT Mobile services). I would like to have my models in a PCL and use them in all of my projects. However, the azure service expects the models to inherit from EntityData, which is found in the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity package. When I try to install that package on the PCL project I get the following error:

```
Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server 1.0.119'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.            0
```

Is there any way to reference the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity package from a PCL or do I have to move all my models to the server project and reference the server project in all my other projects?

Comment: The Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server NuGet package only contains assemblies for .NET 4.5.

Comment: @MattWard My PCL has .Net Framework 4.5 as one of its targets. That is not enough?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Your PCL project only supports a certain subset of APIs provided by .NET 4.5. The Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server NuGet package may use an API not supported by your PCL profile, which is what NuGet is  indicating to you with its error message.