# Failed to install Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication into Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to add / install Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication into my PCL project but there is an error says

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile49', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

I've tried installing the previous version, but the exact same error appeared. I've also tried to changing Framework version to .NET 4.6, but other errors come up.

I want to use GetAppServiceIdentityAsync() method which only supported by that namespace. Is there any other way to add that reference into my PCL project?

Comment: That API is meant for server based services. FYI: Using something like `GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>...` would be a Facebook ToS violation within a mobile app as including the Facebook authorization would be a security issue since anyone could disassemble the app and get the server credentials. This can and does apply to other provider's ToS as well, you would need to review their API ToS.

Comment: Hello @SushiHangover. I didn't know that would be violate any ToS. I want to use that API because I referred this great [post](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/authorization/) by Adrian Hall saying that we can get the extra information from provider using that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps has two versions - one that runs on the server and the other runs on the client.  You are trying to use the server version and that requires ASP.NET and .NET Framework 4.5+ (4.6 at the moment).  It won't work in your client.

If you are using Azure Mobile Apps on the server, then you have already added a referenced to Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client and created a mobile client reference to your Azure App Service.  You have also already configured your Azure Mobile Apps Server and linked your auth provider using Azure App Service Authentication.  If you haven't, check out the book http://aka.ms/zumobook - this will give you the right instruction on this.

If you are still with me, you then need to do a HTTPS connection to your Azure App Service URL + /.auth/me - this returns a JSON blob which contains the provider information that Azure App Service Authentication knows about.  One of the things that the service knows about is the auth token used to authenticate.  You can then use this auth token to get additional information about the user if it isn't in the JSON blob.

A great way to get that information is to use the `client.InvokeApiAsync<>()` method as Bruce mentioned.  This is covered in the book as well.

Comment: Thank you @adrian-hall for your detailed explanation about its usage. I didn't know that it should be used in server version. Before I posted this question, I have implement your   'client.InvokeApiSync<>()' as you mentioned in your book. I just curious about how  GetAppServiceIdentityAsync() can get  more detailed claims.

Comment: Ah, you mentioned in your book in Tip section that :
'You can use the AccessToken property to do Graph API lookups for most providers in a custom API. We'll get into this more in a later chapter.'
I am looking for that chapter explaining that usage but I couldn't find one. Where is it exactly?

Comment: Just use the access token to do Graph API lookups against the auth provider.  You don't need a custom API.  Your mobile client can do the graph API calls itself.  Custom APIs are covered in chapter 4.

Answer (score 2):

As I known, **GetAppServiceIdentityAsync** is used to retrieve the `Identity` ([ProviderCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587449.aspx)) for the specific provider in your server-side code. For your mobile client, I assumed that you could leverage `MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync<List<AppServiceIdentity>>("/.auth/me");` to retrieve the identities and filter them with the specific provider, them you could get `Provider`, `UserId` and `UserClaims` properties as you expected. For more details, you could refer to [Obtaining User Claims](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/authorization/#obtaining-user-claims).

Comment: Yep, I have implemented that function to get UserClaims. I just curious about the usage of 'GetAppServiceIdentityAsync' whether it can be use to get more detailed information from provider. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the Android API Level to a higher level? I had this error by installing Moq and I could solve this problem with changing the Android API Level to the highest API level. Please try to use Android 7.1 (Nougat) with API-Level 25, also at the minimum SDK.

You can change it with: Right click on the project -> Options -> Build -> General -> Android Application

Under General you can also try to change the target version for the app to a higher level.

Comment: I have set my Android API Level to use API Level 25 as Target Framework. I just read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882495/reference-azure-mobile-net-server-sdk-nuget-in-pcl-so-i-can-have-models-in-pcl) and I think it's not about android API stuffs. I think it's because that package only support .NET 4.5.. It gives error since PCL using .NET Portable? I have no idea though. Thank you for the answer anyway